# How do I create a new array and copy the last elements of the old array into the new array while the new array is smaller?

Tags: c++, arrays

The title explains my question, but I will explain in a little more depth. Here is my array initializer that just creates an array with default values going from 0 to i + 1.

```
void initialize(double *a, unsigned size) {
    int val = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        val = i+1;
        a[i] = val;
    }
}
```

Here is where my actual question is. I figured out how to copy the elements of old array into a new one when the size of the new array was bigger, but I can't seem to figure out how to copy the last elements of the old array into a smaller new array. The else if statement is where I want to do that after checking the sizes of the arrays, and what I have there right now does not work.

```
void resize(double *&a, int oldSize, int newSize) {
    double *a1 = new double[newSize]();
    if (newSize > oldSize) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) {
            a1[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
    else if(oldSize > newSize) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        {
        a1[i] = a[oldSize - newSize + i];
        }
    }

    delete [] a;
    a = a1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using arrays instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: I am practicing with arrays as for the assignment.

Comment: Unless you need to use arrays as part of your requirements (school exercise perhaps?) then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. I will make things like copying and resizing *much* easier.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is for an assignment and we are practicing with arrays.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I appreciate the link, but it is a program that is a lot larger than this, and I only posted what was necessary and would run.

Comment: use memcopy. faster. 

 It was segment, add i to offset
a1[i] = a[ oldSize - newSize+i ];

Comment: @kelalaka That did not fix the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I put in the question that I need to save the last elements of old the old array. So if it was a size 5 going to a size 3 array I would need the last 3 elements of the size 5 array.

Comment: @matt My apologies. I did not fully read the title. I recommend placing key information like that in the question body to make sure you also reach inattentive folks like me.

Comment: Why does @kelalaka 's solution not work for you? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to see precisely where things are going wrong?

Comment: @user4581301 It has occurred to me that I may need to change my test methods, because yes as far as I can see that should work.

Comment: If you have a small problem in a large program, copy the small problem out of the big program and put it in a small program. Then you can debug it as a small program. Sometimes you will find the small program proves the problem is not where you thought it was and helps you find the real location. Handy reading: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me

```
void resize(double *&a, int oldSize, int newSize) {
    double *a1 = new double[newSize]();
    if (newSize > oldSize) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) {
            a1[i] = a[i];
        }
    }
    else if(oldSize > newSize) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        {
        a1[i] = a[oldSize - newSize+i];
        }
    }

    delete [] a;
    a = a1;
}
```

25 first size; 10 last elements;

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
>
> 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

Comment: I may need to change around my testing methods, but the code you provided does seem to work, thank you.

Comment: @Matt Read "Programming Pearls" Book by Jon Bentley